# client and server php sql bug

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just cant figure out what is wrong with this code.

I am just sending a username and password to the server, then server sending back a response. Server write to database with no problem, but in the client side sometimes it doesn't reach inside the `if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`. And after it execute the line `alert('login5')`, the jquery animation reset. I know it is the php problem, but I have no idea why it sometimes works but sometimes doesnt, any help is appreciated.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function sendLogin(){

    var xmlhttp;
    var getString;
    var url = "login.php";

    var username=document.getElementById('name').value;
    var password=document.getElementById('pw').value;
    var url= url+ "?username="+username+"&password="+password;


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("get", url , true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

            alert("reached inside");
            getString = xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(getString);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();
    alert('login5');
    //problem here, have to wait a while
}

</script>
```

html code:

```
        <form id="logInBoxes">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" id='name' size="15px">
            <input type="password" placeholder="pw" id='pw' size="10px">
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick='sendLogin()'>
        </form>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$username= $_GET['username'];
$password= $_GET['password'];

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_RAND);
$password = crypt($password, $salt);

$salt = mysql_real_escape_string($salt);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','housescale');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


mysqli_query($sql, "INSERT INTO user (username, password, salt) 
                VALUE 
                ('$username', '$password','$salt')")   or    trigger_error(mysql_error()); 



mysqli_close($sql);

echo $username;


?>
```

edit: it works if I do `alert('login5')` 9 more times in a loop. What exactly does this delay fix imply?

Comment: I'm not particularly sure, I'll post my entire code used during my test instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I used that worked on my end:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function sendLogin() {

        var xmlhttp;
        var getString;
        var url = "login.php";

        var username = document.getElementById( 'name' ).value;
        var password = document.getElementById( 'pw' ).value;
        url = url + "?username=" + username + "&password=" + password; //Don't Need to Re-Declare url Variable

        if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {                              // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
        }

        xmlhttp.open( "get", url , true );
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {

                if( xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {   //Separated readyState and Status

                    alert( "reached inside" );
                    getString = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert( getString );
                }
            }
        };  //Missed Semi-Colon Here

        xmlhttp.send();
        alert( 'login5' );
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="logInBoxes">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" id='name' size="15px">
        <input type="password" placeholder="pw" id='pw' size="10px">
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick='sendLogin()'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    $username= $_GET['username'];
    $password= $_GET['password'];

    $salt = mcrypt_create_iv( 32, MCRYPT_RAND );
    $password = crypt( $password, $salt );

    $sql = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'housescale' );
    $salt = mysqli_real_escape_string( $sql, $salt );
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $sql, $password );

    // Check connection
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query( $sql, "INSERT INTO user ( username, password, salt ) VALUE ( '$username', '$password', '$salt' )" )
        or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    mysqli_close( $sql );

    echo $username;
?>
```

I use Mozilla Firefox 23 on Windows 7. My stack is Uniform Server 8.8.2 (PHP 5.4.14 / MySQL 5.5.30).

I set all the fields in my table to varchar(255) just to be quick. It worked for me with only one issue, sometimes the salt/crypt turned up empty in my database, but that's probably a charset issue because it was able to echo several different combinations just fine.